# Correct typeScript Type for vue3 setup() arguments

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using vue3 with typescript, and I'm using composition API.

```js
export default {
    setup(props, context) {
    },
};
```

This throws an error as follows

Failed to compile.

```
src/components/LoginForm.vue:20:11
TS7006: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    18 |
    19 | export default {
  > 20 |     setup(props, context) {
       |           ^^^^^
```

I know this can be fixed by making `props`, `context` of type any, but that will defeat the purpose of TypeScript.

VS Code intellisense showing me the following type, but I'm not able to find the module from these type are exported.

```
setup?: ((this: void, props: {}, ctx: SetupContext<EmitsOptions>) => void | RenderFunction
```

What is the correct Type for the `setup` function, and from where it is exported ?.

Comment: Type of `props` should be [inferred automatically](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#using-with-composition-api) from your component's `props` option...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The props can not be inferred because you forget to use `defineComponent` method to create your component. To resolve this issue and let props to be infrared by **Vue** you need to wrap your whole object which you are exporting in `defineComponent` method.

More about [***`defineComponent`***](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#definecomponent)

The `<script lang="ts">` part of example Vue 3 composition API component should look like that:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: "PersonComponent",
  props: {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    age: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
    setup(props) {
    const firstName = props.firstName;
    const lastName = props.lastName;
    const age = props.age;
    return {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      age
    };
  }
})
```

[image]

---

[image]

> For more complexd types such as interfaces you need to use `Object as PropType<T>` (`Object as PropType<IconProps>`). More about [`PropType<T>`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props)

Comment: I thought `defineComponent` was for using composition API within Vue v2?

Comment: @Emobe I it part of Vue3. Please take a look at this link to Vue 3 documentation:   _**[`defineComponent`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#definecomponent)**_ which I added in my answer

Comment: Yeah you're right, I noticed it was in there right after I commented. Nice to know it's in there :D